# get_template_part not working on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been working on this for hours and don't know what I'm overlooking or not understanding. I'm trying to use `get_template_part` to call another php document. When I run the code below there is nothing in the `div.content`. I don't understand why my partial-banner.php is being called.

**front-page.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content">

   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/partial', 'banner' ); ?>
   <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**partial-banner.php**

```
<section class="banner">
    <h1>Does this work</h1>
</section>
```

and [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqblv.png) an image of my file structure.

Comment: Do you `have_posts`? Maybe try confirming this with `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`, and also making sure to end your while with `<?php endwhile; else : ?>
 <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>`. Also, you will need to ensure you set `WP_USE_THEMES` to false if you are using your own design: `<?php define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); get_header(); ?>`.

Comment: I tried everything you suggested it didn't help. Nor did it display "Sorry, no posts matched your criteria." If I put a `<p>` inside of the loop it is displayed on the front-page. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a simple PHP include, instead of using WordPress logic

```
<?php include('template-parts/partial-banner.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Solved my issue, thank you.